# NLA animation changes on every render

Tags: nla-editor

This is the first time I'm utilizing the NLA-editor into my animation workflow and I'm having some trouble: it seems like my character is moving in a slightly different manner on every render. I have saved the exact same file on two computers and the other one rendered frames 1-99 and the other one 100-200. When I combine these two animations, there is a jump in the characters position. My feeling is that this is somehow related to playing back the animation first before rendering it, but I'm not sure if that makes sense. Or could this have something to do with "hold" vs. "hold forwards" settings? I have a messy NLA with lot's of different strips and I'm very new to it all.

What could be causing my two renders to behave differently?

Comment: I have the same problem right now,
Did you find a solution or the cause of this issue?

Comment: I belive it had something to do with the way I extended strips. Also sometimes I forgot to exit a strip before rendering. Not really sure though.